# SVG background color not working on Firefox

Tags: html, css, svg

I've encountered some problems regarding the use of an svg. I have the following html and css codes

```
<i id="iconApp" class="icon_approved icon_lg pull-right"></i>

.icon_approved {
    background-color: #fab700;
    display: block;
    mask: url(../Tick-Solid.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    -webkit-mask: url(../Tick-Solid.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background: url(../Tick-Solid.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

The `mask` does not work on firefox, that's why I added the `background` property instead and it works the way I wanted it to be. However, the color does not work as expected. Instead of having a color of `#fab700`, it is instead being interpreted as a background color.

[image]

The orange should be the color of the Icon, not a background color.

Additional info:

I can't find a search term to look for this kind of problem but I did find something similar to my problem.

Link : http://codepen.io/noahblon/post/coloring-svgs-in-css-background-images

Upon looking at the first example, it renders properly on chrome. But if you opened the link on firefox, it appears as boxes (which I assume is background color of the element).

Comment: A mask must point to a mask element within an svg file and not a complete svg file. It's your code that's wrong, not Firefox. You've also set a background colour and seem surprised it acts like a background colour. The post you link to has mistakes in it.

Comment: I've added a comment pointing out the mistake in the blog.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the colour of the contents of an SVG referenced via `background-image`.  All setting `background-color` does is set the fallback colour of the background.  Which is what you are seeing here.

If you want to change the icon colour, you have to change the SVG file.  Or you could inline the SVG in the HTML,  It is also possible to do it via an `<object>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```css
.icon_approved {
  fill: #fab700;
}
```